# What is صلاة (Salat) according/in the Quran?

Tags: quran, salat

What is the general meaning of صلاة (Salat) referred in the Quran?
Please provide verses that mentions the definition/description of Salat, also the rites of the ritual if it was to be treated as such.

Comment: This may be in the Hadith, or in the actual practise handed down by tradition. I'm not sure, someone more knowledgeable may come along.

Answer (score 0):

I found [multiple suras](http://quran.com/search?q=salat) that contain the word al-salat (الصَّلَاةَ). For example this one

> الَّذِينَ يُؤْمِنُونَ بِالْغَيْبِ وَيُقِيمُونَ الصَّلَاةَ وَمِمَّا رَزَقْنَاهُمْ يُنفِقُونَ
>   Sahih International
>   Who believe in the unseen, establish prayer, and spend out of what We have provided for them,
>   2:3

From the translation it means prayer. Is it the general meaning that you seek?

Regarding the description, it appears to me that in Quran the description of salat scatters around the whole book. There is mention of [Zakah](http://quran.com/4/77), [clear of intoxication](http://quran.com/4/43), [shortening the salat](http://quran.com/4/101), [importance of the middle prayer](http://quran.com/2/238), [prostration](http://quran.com/4/102), [ablution](http://quran.com/5/6), [call for prayer](http://quran.com/5/58) and many others.

I think Sunnah is a great source for learning the specifics about salat, especially in [this](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari) and [this](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim). Also there are many websites available explaining the procedures of salat.